# How to access and store the token and use it in other requests with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm using the code below to authenticate myself and get a token.
It works perfectly.

```
    const config = {
        headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ${token}' }
    };
    
    const bodyParameters = {
        username: "teste",
        senha: "123456"
    };
    
    axios.post( 
      'url ...',
      bodyParameters,
      config
    ).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

And the token below:

[image]

My question is: how to access this token and use it in another request?
For example, to get data from this API.

```
    const config2 = {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    };
    
    const bodyParameters2 = {
        cpf: "12345",
        hash: "912409kskllj1u2ou1p4124821"
    };
    
    axios.get( 
      'url..',
      bodyParameters,
      config
    ).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

In this case, I get error: 401 (unauthorized).

--UPDATE--

Update based on interceptors.

```
var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage,
    localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');

    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://www.externalapi.com/', // this way you setup the static part of it and just call the instance with the rest of the specific route
    });

    api.interceptors.request.use(config => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        if (token) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }

        return config;
    });

exports.novaSolicitacao = (req, res) => {

    
    const bodyParameters = {
        username: "teste",
        senha: "123456"
    };

    api.post(
        '/login',
        bodyParameters,
    ).then(console.log).catch(console.log);

    const bodyParameters2 = {
        cpf: "123456",
        aceite: true,
    };

    app.get( 
        '/search',
        bodyParameters2,
        config
      ).then(console.log).catch(error);
```

I made this update to the code, but I get this error:

```
    data: {
      statusCode: 404,
      error: 'SESSIONTOKENEXPIRED',
      message: 'O token expirou.'
    }
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
```

Comment: change quotations from 'Bearer ${token}' to `Bearer ${token}`

Comment: use these qutations ``

Comment: token is not defined.

Comment: Why you want to reuse the same authorization token for another request?

Comment: It doesn't really matter that it's the same. It would only be accessing the order!